# IllegalStateException on Eclipse debug

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I'm becoming mad because of this problem. I've searched a lot through the internet but no one is experiencing this problem like in my case.

What i'm doing is trying to debug a simple android app with my phone and Eclipse with ADT, composed by a TextView and a Button. 
The button should write something in the TextView but actually I left the "Send" function empty.
Everytime i press that button, the app closes and in the Eclipse debug log there is an "IllegalStateException" error, related to a function called "ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(), on line: 745

This is my code:

Main Activiy.java

```
package com.android_test.examples;
import com.example.android_test.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
        {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
    protected void Send()
    {           

    }
}
```

and activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <requestFocus />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:onClick="Send()"
        android:text="Invia" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnok"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm really becoming mad because of this, please someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `protected void Send() {}`

with

```
 public void Send(View view) {}
```

and remove the brackets from the `onClick` property:

```
android:onClick="Send"
```

Comment: thank you so much, i've solved this problem, but the sad thing is that now it says "ClassCastException" on line "TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt)"

Comment: change the id of the RelativeLayout in something else and run it again

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
public void Send(View v)
{           

}
```

and change

```
android:onClick="Send()"
```

to

```
android:onClick="Send"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

`android:onClick`

> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is
>   clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes
>   exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify
>   android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void
>   sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).

Comment: thank you so much, i've solved this problem, but the sad thing is that now it says "ClassCastException" on line "TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);